# Hiding non-contiguous rows in excel using checkboxes

Tags: excel, checkbox, hide, rows

I am trying to hide several non-contiguous rows in excel using checkboxes. I have had success in hiding rows that are next to each other, but not a range of rows that are not. Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()

If CheckBox6 = True Then


Range("Report!45:45,Report!46:46,Report!48:48,Report!50:50").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else: [Report!45:51].EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
[Report!45:51].EntireRow.Hidden = False

If CheckBox6 = True Then
    Worksheets("Report").Range("47:47,49:49,51:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    [Report!45:51].EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, but I also would like rows 49 and 51 hidden along with 47. I wrote it this way, but it didn't work:                                    
                                                                                                          
   `Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
    [Report!45:51].EntireRow.Hidden = False

    If CheckBox6 = True Then
    Worksheets("Report").Rows(47, 49, 51).Hidden = True
Else
    [Report!45:51].EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub`

Comment: Sorry--this is the first time using a forum like this for me. I can't figure out how to go to the next line without it submitting my comment. It's the same as your code, but I added "(47,49,51)" in it.

Comment: try this line instead: `Worksheets("Report").Range("47:47,49:49,51:51").EntireRow.Hidden = true`

Comment: If I do that, it gives me a "runtime error: '1004' - Unable to set the hidden property of the Range Class.

Comment: There were some typos in the line, try copying and pasting from the code in the answer and not the comments.